# ggplotly plotting multiple timeseries as barchart with dynamicTicks = T

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, plotly

I want to plot multiple timeseries as a barchart wih `plotly` + `ggplot2` but I am having problems when using `dynamicTicks = TRUE`. The bar-width of one dataset increases and spreads over a bigger timeframe, compared to the other dataset which I want to avoid.

By setting `dynamicTicks = FALSE` the width (of the red bars in the example) looks correct, but the x-Axis labels disappear when zooming in.

Changing the x-values to character would also make the width look correct, but the labels of the x-Axis overlap and dont inherit any logic.

**How can I set the bar-width of one dataset to the same as another dataset, keeping the x values in Date format and having `dynamicTicks = TRUE`?**

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(data.table)

## Data
data1 <- {data.table(
  time_stamp = seq.Date(as.Date("2018-01-01"), to = as.Date("2018-07-04"), by = 1),
  q = runif(185, 100, 5000), qall = sample(1:8, size = 185, T),
  col = sample(c("green", "lightgreen", "yellow"), 185,T)
)}
data2 <- {data.table(
  time_stamp = seq.Date(as.Date("2018-01-01"), to = as.Date("2018-07-01"), by = 7),
  q = runif(26, 100, 5000), qall = sample(1:8, size = 26, T)
)}


key <- highlight_key(data1, ~time_stamp)
maxY = max(data1$q)
p <- ggplot() +
  geom_col(data = data2, aes(x = (time_stamp), y = maxY, 
                         text = paste("I AM TOO WIDE: <br>Date: ", (time_stamp))), 
           width = 1, fill = "red", alpha=0.4) +
  geom_col(data = key, aes(x = (time_stamp), y = q),
           width = 1, color="gray", fill = data1$col) +
  theme(text = element_text(size=9), axis.text.x = element_text(angle=0, hjust=1))

## Too Wide red bars + Correct x labels
dp <- ggplotly(p, source = "src", dynamicTicks = T, 
               tooltip = c("text")) %>% 
  highlight(off="plotly_doubleclick", color = "blue", opacityDim = 0.8); 
dp
```

---

The image on the left has `dynamicTicks = T` and too wide red bars, and the one on the right has `dynamicTicks = FALSE`, correct red bars but no real xAxis logic. 
[image]

I tried to set those options without success:

```
# plotly_json(dp)

dp$x$data[[1]]$width = rep(1, length(dp$x$data[[1]]$width))
dp
dp$x$data[[1]]$width = s$time_stamp
dp
dp$x$data[[1]]$marker$line$width = 1
dp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `dynamicTicks = TRUE`, `ggplotly` adjusts the column width depending on the spacing between observations of the single traces. In the case of `data2` this is 7 days while for `data1` is only one day.

A way to solve this issue is to add observations to `data2`; for example replace `data2` with the following:

```
library(tidyverse)
data3 = 
  data2 %>%
  mutate(maxY = max(data1$q)) %>% 
  complete(time_stamp = seq.Date(from = min(data2$time_stamp),
                                 to = max(data2$time_stamp),
                                 by = 1)
  ) %>% 
  replace_na(list(maxY=0))
```

Note that you need the last `replace_na` since columns with `y=0` will not be rendered by `plotly` whereas `NA`s will be removed and you will get the wider columns again.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. I also had the same thought, but kept `y=0` or `NA`, so it didn't render correctly. So far I can't see any problems with that solution.